# How to render data from API response in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

how to initialize response from API to variable so I can use it in my `render()` function? Why `component.setState` is not working? 
Error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined(…)*

```
class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: 23
    };
 }

  componentDidMount() {
var component = this;


      fetch('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/alltime')
          .then(function(response) {
              return response.json()
          }).then(function(json) {
              var data = json;
              console.log(data[0]);
              console.log(data[0].username);
              component.setState({
                  data: json
              })
          })

  }




  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>elo{this.state.data[0].username}</h1>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

const docs = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render( <Main/> , docs);
```

Comment: You should have a guard statement / ternary operator in your render method if you plan on using some data that will arrive at a later time. Something like this: var someData = this.state.data[0].username || "";

Comment: @JustinHerter console.logs in fetch logs proper data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that on first render this "this.state.data[0].username" is not set, until the response comes back from the API call.

Something like this in your render method should work:

```
render() {
    var someData = this.state.data[0].username || "";
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>elo{someData}</h1>


      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting parsing error when i put variable in return statement.
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token (39:6) while parsing file`
I'm using browserify + babelify in my gulpfile

Comment: @KAT sorry my mistake, I moved the declaration outside the return function.