# How to load data on button click using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my below code i have one table and when i select radio button and click on submit button then load the data and show in console. this is fine.

but in my table i have many data in table body. and when i select 1st row radio button then click submit button, then load data and show in console. that is fine. but again i select 2nd row radio button and click submit button, then i am not able to fetch data and show in console. and again i select the 3rd row and select radio button and click submit button then i m getting data in console.like that

why i'm getting like this?

```
class ProvFileRptSearchResult extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super();
  
    this.state = {
        pymtDetails:[],
        data: [],
        rowDetails:[],
        checkbox: false
        
       };
    //    this.handleFile=this.handleFile.bind(this);
         this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
   
}
    handleClick() {
        const apiUrl = "https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e";
        if (this.state.checkbox) {
          fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              this.setState({ data: data });
              console.log("This is your data", data);
              window.open("https://example.com", "_blank");
            })
        } else {
          alert("Data not fetched!");
        }
        // console.log('click');
      }




render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="table-employee" style={{ marginTop:"20px",border:" 1.5px solid darkgray" }}>
            <table className="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead>
            <tr >
            <th scope="col">Select</th>
            <th scope="col"> LOAD DATE</th>
            <th scope="col"> FILE DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> SERVICE</th>
                <th scope="col"> PROVISIONER CODE </th>
                <th scope="col"> DESCRIPTION</th>
                
               
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                     {
                     this.props.customerDetails.map((type,j)=>{
                        return(
 
                        <tr> 
                        <td ><input type="radio" preventDefault name="select"  key={j}  onClick={(e) =>this.rowSelected(j)} value={this.state.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      this.setState({ checkbox: !this.state.checkbox })
                    }/></td>
                         <td> {type.provis_file_stamp}</td>
                          <td> {type.provis_file_hdrdt}</td>
                          <td> {type.service_code}</td>
                            <td>{type.provisioner_code}</td>
                            <td>{type.provisioner_desc}</td>   
                            
                            </tr>
                        )
                     })
                         
                }

            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-submit" >
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{marginRight:"30px"}}  type="submit" onClick={this.handleClick}>FILE</button>
                               
                        </div>
            
    </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: anybody help me on that??

Comment: @AjeetShah so can i make it true checkbox: true like that but not worked yet

Comment: @AjeetShah or plz can u show me something any other idea.its very thankful

Comment: @AjeetShah yes i  already try which u shared link to use radio button but not worked can u plz show me something in here https://codesandbox.io/s/o8tu5?file=/index.js its very thankful

Comment: @AjeetShah thanks for help and support thanku

Comment: @AjeetShah one more help but i want to make when i click first row then open url and again i click 2nd row then open different url same again i click 3rd row then open different url.how can we do that isit possible to do that like that

Comment: yes right i want open different different url like when i select 1st row then open this url  http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_brown.png and when select 2nd row then open this url https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png and when select 3rd row then open this https://example.com/  like that

Comment: @AjeetShah yes thanks its fine  but in that case u select value A1,A2,A3 on each input type radio button   that but in my project i have only one  input type radio button and all data come in database.so in that case how can we do that  .in here i have so many tr so we do that easliy but in my project all data come in databse so how can we do in that case

Comment: i have only one tr in my actual project <td ><input type="radio" preventDefault name="select"  key={j}  onClick={(e) =>this.rowSelected(j)} value={this.state.checkbox}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      this.setState({ checkbox: !this.state.checkbox })
                    }/></td>

Comment: <td> {type.provis_file_stamp}</td>
                          <td> {type.provis_file_hdrdt}</td>
                          <td> {type.service_code}</td>
                            <td>{type.provisioner_code}</td>
                            <td>{type.provisioner_desc}</td>

Comment: @AjeetShah is it possible to do that in one tr?? to open different different URL on the basis of select radio button

Comment: Your questions are changing every time we answer. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/329117). This is not the way to ask questions on StackOverflow. Always ask the original question. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/329117). If your problem is not a toy project (for learning), you should consider using a good library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table. Also, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2873538) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yaa sure thanks @AjeetShah i have update my code .can u check and give me any idea and suggestion on that in above code

Comment: @AjeetShah its very thankful  to u give me some idea and suggestion in my above code.I am stuck on that part actually.

Comment: Try https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-b399o?file=/index.js Don't fetch data from `https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e` everytime. Just fetch it once and use it further.

Comment: @AjeetShah thanks for ur great help but in code ur create  this but is it possible to without create this const ,and fetch id in my api .const customerDetails = [
  {
    id: 1,
    provis_file_stamp: "a",
    provis_file_hdrdt: "b",
    service_code: "c",
    provisioner_code: "d",
    provisioner_desc: "e"
  },

Comment: bcz i have so many data so every we cant create id manually right ?? @AjeetShah

Comment: Yes, it is possible to render table data from API data but you can do it by yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40594269/2873538 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44911012/2873538

Comment: is it possible to can we connect in mail ?? so that i can share my file or can u help me out something bcz i m stuck on that @AjeetShah

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is, you are handling the data using single state variable.

take three separate variables for  all your radio buttons

and handle them separately

Comment: how can we do that using variable seprately  https://codesandbox.io/s/o8tu5?file=/index.js can u show me something in here

Answer (score 0):

you need some changes in checkbox value and input tags values and setstate,you can find the changes. below is the code that works:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      checkbox: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const apiUrl = "https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e";
    if (this.state.checkbox) {
      fetch(apiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ data: data });
          console.log("This is your data", data);
          window.open("https://example.com", "_blank");
        });
    } else {
      alert("not load data!");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="table-employee"
          style={{ marginTop: "20px", border: " 1.5px solid darkgray" }}
        >
          <table className="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Select</th>
                <th scope="col"> LOAD DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> FILE DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> SERVICE</th>
                <th scope="col"> PROVISIONER CODE </th>
                <th scope="col"> DESCRIPTION</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input
                    value={this.state.checbox === 1 ? true : false}
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ checkbox: 1 })}
                    type="radio"
                    preventDefault
                    name="select"
                  />
                </td>

                <td>dfgrty</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>erer</td>
                <td>uuio</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input
                    value={this.state.checbox === 2 ? true : false}
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ checkbox: 2 })}
                    type="radio"
                    preventDefault
                    name="select"
                  />
                </td>

                <td>dfgrty</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>erer</td>
                <td>uuio</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input
                    value={this.state.checbox === 1 ? true : false}
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({ checkbox: 3 })}
                    type="radio"
                    preventDefault
                    name="select"
                  />
                </td>

                <td>dfgrty</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>erer</td>
                <td>uuio</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div className="btn-submit">
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ marginRight: "30px" }}
            type="submit"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));

// https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e
// http://codeskulptor-assets.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/assets_clock_minute_arrow.png
```

Comment: which u posted in code i m run here but i m getting error check here https://codesandbox.io/s/o8tu5?file=/index.js

Comment: I had used the star(**) mark to bold the changes, now I have edited the code and removed the marks, check it again. Now code is updated.

Comment: thenks for help but i want to make when i select 1st row then click submit button then open url and again when i select 2st row then click submit button then open another url like that 3rd row. ist possible to do that

Comment: actually i did not get what do you mean exactly, but if your concern is about blank! you can open the url thru  window.open("https://example.com", "_blank"); in seperate tabs or in one tab by using  window.open("https://example.com", "blank");

Comment: no i am trying to say that i have only one tr in my actual project means i have one input type radio button so how can we do that in one tr